# Laravel 5.6, create on the fly property

Tags: php, laravel

With:

```
Users::all();
```

I have all the users according to my db columns. In my case, I have

```
id|name|first_name
```

But I need to have the `name` and `last_name` in the same key.

Is there any option of Laravel 5.6 to create on the fly another column to that Users collection?

Something like:

```
Users::createColumn('fullname', ['name, 'last_name');
```

or something like that.

EDIT:

Right now I'm doing this:

```
$users = User::all();

$users->map(function ($fullname) {
    $fullname['fullname'] = $fullname->name . ' ' . $fullname->last_name;
        return $fullname;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Laravel's Accessors & Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) is what you're looking for.

In your User.php model:

```php
/**
 * Get the user's full name.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getFullnameAttribute()
{
    return "{$this->name} {$this->last_name}";
}
```

Then, you access it like so:

```php
$user->fullname
```